# Oracle-SQL : Select daily basis of count(item) between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need to spread a row with specified range of dates (`STARTDATE`, `ENDDATE`) into multiple rows with successive dates from the range. Please see the image below

[image]

Here is example of the data

```
> MODELCD  PRODUCTCD  PROCESSCD  LS_PROCESSCD  EST_STARTDATE  EST_ENDDATE
   P9218   22186844   15VV2111    DS            21/12/2015     10/1/2016
   P9218   22269836   15VV2121    MC            23/2/2016      21/3/2016
   P9218   22186844   15VV2111    MC            9/2/2016       7/3/2016
```

And the expected result shown as below

```
 MODELCD  PRODUCTCD  PROCESSCD  LS_PROCESSCD  PROCESS_DATE  
 P9218    22186844   15VV2111   DS            21/12/2015     
 P9218    22186844   15VV2111   DS            22/12/2015
 P9218    22186844   15VV2111   DS            23/12/2015
   '         '         '        '               '
   '         '         '        '               '
   '         '         '        '               '
 P9218   22186844   15VV2111    DS            10/01/2016
 P9218   22269836   15VV2121    MC            23/2/2016      
 P9218   22269836   15VV2121    MC            24/2/2016
   '         '         '         '                '
   '         '         '         '                '
   '         '         '         '                '
 P9218   22269836   15VV2121    MC            21/3/2016
```

Comment: In this case, I want to select `process_cd` for daily basis start with `est_startdate` and end with `est_enddate`. 
The data have process "DS" between 4/1/2016 and 17/1/2016. According to the date range number of days is 13 as same as the number of records I should get.

Date        Modelcd  Part  Jobno  Processcd 
4/1/2016      xxx    xxx   xxx      DS
5/1/2016      xxx    xxx   xxx      DS
.              .      .     .       .
.              .      .     .       .
.              .      .     .       .
17/1/2016     xxx    xxx   xxx      DS

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result as formatted text; what you tried so far?

Comment: How many intervals do you have? Do you need it for a single interval or for may starting rows  with different intervals?

Comment: @Aleksej I've posted the data and the expected results. I want the daily record for these date intervals. All I need is single intervals. I want to select the LS_PROCESSCD for each day between the range of EST_STARTDATE AND EST_ENDDATE.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT t.ModelCD,
           t.PART,
           t.JOBNO,
           t.PROCESSCD,
           STARTDATE + LEVEL
   FROM Table t
   WHERE PROCESSCD = 'DS.'
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ENDDATE - STARTDATE;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not the result I want because my explanation is not clear. From, the data I have process "DS" between 4/1/2016 and 17/1/2016.  so I have number of records = 13 as same as number of days calculated from enddate(17/1/2016) - startdate(4/1/2016)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it takes much time to run this code then crash.

Comment: @Worrawan285 well the 'Connect by' is definitely your solution here. You didn't supply us with the information about the scheme and kind of data you will have there. So I suggest you to study the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) and find out the right query by yourself. Good luck